# sas function if first.value

Tags: function, sas

I have a data set with timestamps and id's.  Each id has several timestamp values. Sometimes the times are the  same and other times they are different.
I sort the data by id then timestamp. 
And then I pass it to the function if first.value.
Then I do a proc freq, to count records, and each time the proc freq gives me a slightly different count for some of the id's.  The overall total count doesn't change but some of the values are shifted, so for example for id the counts are  a=125 and id b=130  If I run the code again, the values will be id a=126 and id b=129. The total counts remain the same, but the values slightly change.
I sort by the same variable as I use in the first.value function. I also tried proc sort nodupkey and used equals and noequals as an option.
Is there some other way to keep only the earliest record for each id?
Thanks.

```
proc sort data=a out=b ; 
by id time ; 
run; 

data c; 
set b; 
IF FIRST.id; 
BY id time; 
run;
```

Comment: Can you post the exact code you used?  Is the goal to get one record per ID?

Comment: proc sort data=a  out=b ;
by id time ;
run;  data c; 
set b;
IF FIRST.id;
BY id time;  
run;

Comment: It is bad style to have the IF statement between the SET and BY statements, but it probably will not impact the data step.  If you are seeing changes in the number of distinct ID values then it should be caused by changes in the input data.

Comment: I don't refresh my source data table so it can be caused by the changes in data. What if I use the nodupkey with the NOEQUALS option instead?

Comment: Just use NODUPKEY to find the unique ID values. Shouldn't make any difference in the result.  Are the counts you are seeing from something that is referencing some variable other than ID? Perhaps you have a different pattern of missing values for some other variable that is causing your counting step to generate different results.

Comment: Actually I think you're  right I should exclude all the null or blank counts.

Comment: But why not still use the noequals option in the sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code should work fine.  But it will only have 1 observation per value of ID.  So if you are seeing 129 observations with ID='a' then you have done something different than you posted.

So let's use SASHELP.CLASS as an example dataset that is available to all SAS users.  We will treat AGE as the id variable and NAME as the order variable within id.  So these two steps will create a table with the first person per age.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=one ;
  by age name ;
run;
data want ;
 set one;
 by age;
 if first.age;
run;
```

If you run PROC FREQ or PRINT you will see that there is only one record per value of AGE.

```
proc freq data=want;
  tables age;
run;
proc print data=want;
  var age name;
run;
```

If you are getting different values for variables other than ID and DATE in the output then that means your input has duplicate records with the same values of ID and DATE.  To have it consistently pick the same value the you could try using the EQUALS option to make it preserve in the relative order. However if your input is from a database then perhaps it will not support that.  You could look for other key variables to add to the BY statement on the SORT.  You could also try sorting an all of the variables.

```
proc sort data=have out=want ;
  by id date _all_ ;
run;
data want;
   set want;
   by id;
   if first.id;
run;
```

Comment: I think you're correct. There are duplicate records with the same values of ID and Date.  I found another variable I can use for an ID and used your code above and got consistent counts...I ran it five times just to be sure. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you do have to sort twice.

```
proc sort data=a out=b; 
by id time ; 
run; 

proc sort data=b nodupkey;
by id;
run;
```

From the documentation NOEQUALS does not maintain the order of the output, which is important in this case.

> EQUALS|NOEQUALS
>   specifies the order of the observations in the output data set. For observations with identical BY-variable values, EQUALS maintains the relative order of the observations within the input data set in the output data set. NOEQUALS does not necessarily preserve this order in the output data set.

Comment: No it still doesn't work. I excluded the nulls and blanks and sorted twice but the counts aren't consistent between each code iteration.

Comment: You have something else going on. Take a snapshot of your data and test on that or post your code at least.